# Fedora Touchpad Stopped Working After Update

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, mouse, touchpad, acer

So I am on the latest version of Fedora. I have an Acer Aspire E15. I did a dnf update about a week ago (it was probably two weeks out of date at that point) and shutdown. I didn't turn it on again until now. The touchpad (mouse movement and click), the wireless Logitech mouse I usually use (M510), AND the wifi have all three stopped working. Wonderful. They had been working fine before for months. I did another dnf update through a wired connection and rebooted. It fixed none of the three issues.

I have no idea what to do at this point. Please help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it help if you boot into an older kernel? You should have that option at the initial boot prompt.

Comment: I would have tried that, but unfortunately there are no older kernels listed on boot as usual.

Comment: That's kind of odd. Maybe something catastrophic went wrong?

Comment: It hasn't been showing them for a while though. Perhaps something got messed up related to the kernel backups prior to this, but I don't believe it is a related incident.

Comment: Can you try the F24 (out tomorrow, officially!) live media to see if things work with that?

Comment: I suppose I can, but the touchpad works fine in the F23 live media. I had to install a ton of stuff to get the wireless mouse and wifi working though.

Comment: That's weird; especially the mouse. I'm using an M505 right now and it just works, and I'm pretty sure the protocol is the same.